# Invalid Exception

Tags: java, oop, exception, custom-exceptions

So I programmed this exception for a lab I'm doing:

```
public class InvalidDNAException extends Exception{
   public InvalidDNAException(String message){
      super(message);
       }
}
```

and then tried to put the exception into the class I'm using for the lab

```
try { for (int i=0;i<nucleo.length();i++){
        //code to be implemented later
        else throw InvalidDNAException("Invalid DNA String");
      }
}
catch(InvalidDNAException e){
         System.out.print("Invalid string");
         System.exit(0);
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
cannot find symbol
     else throw InvalidDNAException("Invalid DNA String");
                ^
  symbol:   method InvalidDNAException(String)
  location: class DNA
```

Did I just not create the exception correctly or what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `new`:

```
else throw new InvalidDNAException("Invalid DNA String");
//         ^^^ this is important
```

Also, you shouldn't just throw an exception only to catch it and `System.exit` in the same method. If you're not going to write the code to deal with a checked exception properly, at least wrap it in an unchecked exception so you get the stack trace:

```
catch (InvalidDNAException e) {
         // You really ought to do something better than this.
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the keyword `new`. Change your line to

```
 throw new InvalidDNAException("Invalid DNA String");
```

Answer (score 0):

`throw InvalidDNAException("Invalid DNA String");` is not a valid syntax

`InvalidDNAException` is a class and you need to call the **constructor** by doing:

```
throw new InvalidDNAException("Invalid DNA String");
```